# Getting content of a tag in LINQ to XML with namespaces

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I need to get the content of the POIssuedDate tag of the below XML using LINQ. Below is the code I wrote that I think should work.

EDIT : Just tried with XNamespace bat = @"x-commerceone:document:btsox:Batch.sox$1.0"; and XNamespace bat = @"urn:x-commerceone:document:btsox:Batch.sox$1.0"; both dont work.

The code throws an exception "Sequence contains no elements" which i expect if nothing matches given im using the First() method

**Code**

```
XDocument baseXML = XDocument.Load(Path.Combine(XMLFolder + @"\Provide.xml"));
XNamespace bat = @"xmlns:bat=""urn:x-commerceone:document:btsox:Batch.sox$1.0";

string date = baseXML.Descendants(bat + "Batch").Elements("PurchaseOrder").Elements("OrderHeader").Elements("POIssuedDate").First().Value;
```

**XML**

```
<?soxtype urn:x-commerceone:document:btsox:Batch.sox$1.0?>
<?import urn:x-commerceone:document:telcoapisox:ServiceRequestOrder.sox$1.0?>
<?import urn:x-commerceone:document:com:commerceone:CBL:CBL.sox$1.0?>
<?import urn:x-commerceone:document:btsox:DSL.sox$1.0?>
<bat:Batch BatchID="B-15-6-2001-4" NoOfEntries="3" xmlns="urn:x-commerceone:document:com:commerceone:CBL:CBL.sox$1.0" xmlns:bat="urn:x-commerceone:document:btsox:Batch.sox$1.0" xmlns:sro="urn:x-commerceone:document:telcoapisox:ServiceRequestOrder.sox$1.0" xmlns:dsl="urn:x-commerceone:document:btsox:DSL.sox$1.0">
  <PurchaseOrder>
    <OrderHeader>
      <POIssuedDate>20010615T15:12:03</POIssuedDate>
..SNIP
    </OrderHeader>
  </PurchaseOrder>
</bat:Batch>
```

Comment: You say the code you "think should work" - does it not? If not, what is wrong with it?

Comment: XNamespace bat = @"urn:x-commerceone:document:btsox:Batch.sox$1.0"; http://msdn.microsoft.com/us-en/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XNamespace bat = @"urn:x-commerceone:document:btsox:Batch.sox$1.0";
XNamespace ns  = @"urn:x-commerceone:document:com:commerceone:CBL:CBL.sox$1.0";

string date = baseXML.Descendants(bat + "Batch").Elements(ns + "PurchaseOrder").Elements(ns + "OrderHeader").Elements(ns + "POIssuedDate").First().Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

The namespace shouldn't include the "xmlns:bat" part:

```
XNamespace bat = "urn:x-commerceone:document:btsox:Batch.sox$1.0";
XNamespace ns = "urn:x-commerceone:document:com:commerceone:CBL:CBL.sox$1.0";
```

In addition, you have to specify the namespace for **every** element:

```
string date = baseXML.Descendants(bat + "Batch")
                     .Elements(ns + "PurchaseOrder")
                     .Elements(ns + "OrderHeader")
                     .Elements(ns + "POIssuedDate")
                     .First().Value
```

Comment: That dosent work either. The subsiquent elements dont have the namespace on them?

Comment: The subelements do have a namespace (the default namespace). But my example is indeed wrong. You also have to specify what the default namespace is. I'll correct it